# i18n-js on Rails 2.3.5 installation

Tags: javascript, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-2

I feel like a moron because this gem seems to be a widely used, but I can't set it up.

I'm on the [i18n-js github page](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) and I'm following the instructions:

```
gem install i18n-js
rake i18n:js:setup # Rails <= 3.0
```

And, though the gem is is now installed, I get:

> Don't know how to  build task 'i18n:js:setup'

Which it's actually no big surprise because I don't think it's enough to have the gem in your gemlist to add some task, right?

I also tried adding this line below, but, though the gem it's now shown as a dependency and I can access `SimplesIdeias::I18n`, the rake task is still not available.

```
# environment.rb
config.gem 'i18n-js'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your Rakefile :

```
require 'i18n-js'
require 'i18n-js/rake'
```

After you have this rake task.

If you see the rake task : https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/master/lib/i18n-js/rake.rb

You can emulate this task in your console and do :

`SimplesIdeias::I18n.setup!`

Comment: I noticed I could have triggered it manually but I didn't want to start with the wrong foot and get into other troubles, though it's a quite simple gem. Thank you @shingara for coming to the rescue once again.

Comment: `require 'i18n-js'` is also needed from the task